Html button to create SVG shapes on screen
I'm doing an assignment that asks for buttons that generate SVG shapes. I can get a single shape from a button by calling a Javascript function. But then it doesn't spawn any more.
I thought they might be on top of each other, so I created increasing variables for spawn location, but that didn't do anything.
I also need to make color/fill a variable to change it, but SVG formatting is so different in Javascript vs in the html page that I can't get that working either.
HTML:
<button type="button" class="buttonC" onclick="circle()">Circle</button>
<button type="button" class="buttonR">Rectangle</button>
<button type="button" class="buttonL">Line</button>

<svg id="svg"></svg>

And Js:
 var x = 25;
 var y = 25;

 function circle() {
     var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
     var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
         circle.cx.baseVal.value = x+40;
         circle.cy.baseVal.value = y+40;
         circle.r.baseVal.value = 20;
     svg.appendChild(circle);
 }


given that x is a constant, x+40 is a constant too, i.e. it will always be 65 so you're still drawing everything at the same place. You could try using Math.random

Learn SVG first, create the shapes and fills by hand. Only after you understand how SVG works continue with creating (or maybe easier altering) the SVG with JavaScript. Otherwise you are learning 2 technologies at once.

The below solution generates circles with random x-/y- & r-attributes as well as a random color and places them into the SVG element. I added several comments that explain what the code does so you can follow along.


var svg = document.getElementById('svg'); // Save a reference to the element

function getRgbColor() {
  // Returns a random RGB string. Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
  // ensures the value of the respective channel never exceeds
  // the range 0 - 255
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  return 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
}

function randomAttributes(svgElement) {
  // Takes in the <svg> element the shape is to be inserted to and calculates
  // cx, cy, r & fill attribute values for it. Chooses a random position
  // inside the <svg> element for the cx/cy values and calcuates the radius
  // in relation to the shortest side of the <svg>. Returns an object with the
  // calculated values
  var shortestSide = Math.min(svgElement.scrollWidth, svgElement.scrollHeight);
  return {
    cx: Math.floor(Math.random() * svgElement.scrollWidth),
    cy: Math.floor(Math.random() * svgElement.scrollHeight),
    r: Math.max(1, Math.random() * shortestSide),
    fill: getRgbColor()
  };
}

function circle() {
  var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
  
  // generate the attributes
  var attributes = randomAttributes(svg);
  
  // instead of property assignment, use .setAttribute
  circle.setAttribute('cx', attributes.cx);
  circle.setAttribute('cy', attributes.cy);
  circle.setAttribute('r', attributes.r);
  circle.setAttribute('fill', attributes.fill);
     
  svg.appendChild(circle);
}
<button type="button" class="buttonC" onclick="circle()">Circle</button>
<button type="button" class="buttonR">Rectangle</button>
<button type="button" class="buttonL">Line</button>
<svg id="svg"></svg>
 



EDIT
You can develop the solution further by more separation: randomAttributes for example calculates the radius as well as the x-/y-position for the circle. Instead of adding a randomAttributesRectangle function, it is possible to refactor randomAttributes into separate functions for each attribute so they can be reused for all shapes:


var svg = document.getElementById('svg');

function getRgbColor() {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  return 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
}

function getPosition(svgElement) {
  return {
    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * svgElement.scrollWidth),
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * svgElement.scrollHeight)
  };
}

function getSize(svgElement) {
  var shortestSide = Math.min(svgElement.scrollWidth, svgElement.scrollHeight);
  return Math.max(1, Math.random() * shortestSide);
}

function circle() {
  var shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
  
  var position = getPosition(svg);
  
  shape.setAttribute('cx', position.x);
  shape.setAttribute('cy', position.y);
  shape.setAttribute('r', getSize(svg));
  shape.setAttribute('fill', getRgbColor());
     
  svg.appendChild(shape);
}

function rectangle() {
  var shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
  
  var position = getPosition(svg);
  
  shape.setAttribute('x', position.x);
  shape.setAttribute('y', position.y);
  shape.setAttribute('width', getSize(svg));
  shape.setAttribute('height', getSize(svg));
  shape.setAttribute('fill', getRgbColor());
     
  svg.appendChild(shape);
}

function line() {
  var shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
  
  var positionA = getPosition(svg);
  var positionB = getPosition(svg);
  
  shape.setAttribute('x1', positionA.x);
  shape.setAttribute('y1', positionA.y);
  shape.setAttribute('x2', positionB.x);
  shape.setAttribute('y2', positionB.y);
  shape.setAttribute('stroke', getRgbColor());
     
  svg.appendChild(shape);
}
<button type="button" class="buttonC" onclick="circle()">Circle</button>
<button type="button" class="buttonR" onclick="rectangle()">Rectangle</button>
<button type="button" class="buttonL" onclick="line()">Line</button>
<svg id="svg"></svg>
 



